# VBA loop to find all values in col Q that equal 1300, then change value

Tags: excel, vba

So i am trying to change all values in col Q to a % (not out of 1, but *100). I would say 80% of the values are usually correct automatically (2.5, 3, 3.5, etc), but sometimes I get a 1300 that needs to be changed to its decimal.

The equation to do that is =1300/P(cell#)*100

Is it possible to loop through all cells and change the 1300 value to the above equation?

Thanks for any help, and this is what I have so far

```
Dim rng As Range


Set rng = Range("Q2:Q" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = 1300 Then
        cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, 13).Value
        End If
    Next
```

currently it is replacing the value in Q that equals 1300 with the corresponding value in AD.

Comment: what is P(Cell#) ?

Comment: so if we are talking about Q500, then it would be P500, basically the same row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can form the Equation using Offset, you were on the right path.

`Cell.Value = Cell.Value / (Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value * 100)`

**Try:**

```
Dim rng As Range


Set rng = Range("Q2:Q" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)

    For Each Cell In rng
        If Cell.Value = 1300 Then
            Cell.Value = Cell.Value / (Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value * 100)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Perfect. Only thing is the *100 has to be on the outside of the parenthesis. Not sure why, but it when its inside the () it goes to the hundreths place. Thank you